# use cygwin from cmd.exe

Tags: windows, cmd

is it possible to use cygwin from cmd.exe in Windows?

i want to do following

```
FOR /L %G in (1 1 100) DO sshpass -p "password" scp  E:\in\File%G.csv openstack@remotecomp:/testfiles/
```

transfer 100 files from windows to unix computer

now question:

can i use sshpass and scp from cmd.exe as long as cygwin is installed? or do i have to use cygwin terminal?

and do the files which i want to transfer neccessarily have to be in cygwin's folder?

goal is to use this one command in a BPEL activity, and as such there should not be any kind of user interaction when the command is run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the full paths to the binaries, or create a wrapper script and call that to do the cygwin commands, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
# doit.sh wrapper script in home dir of cygwin user
echo "got args $@"
```

and call it from windows shell with

```
for /L %G in (1 1 100) DO c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "/home/youruser/doit.sh %G"
```

in this case it prints 1..100 out, but your wrapper script can do all the ssh stuff it needs to instead.

For a more complex script, you can pass params from windows to the shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# callssh.sh
COUNT_NUM=$1
PASSWORD=$2
FILE_PATH=$(cygpath $3)

sshpass -p $PASSWORD scp $FILE_PATH openstack@whereever:/some/path/
```

and you'd call it with

```
for /L %G in (1 1 100) DO c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "/home/youruser/callssh.sh %G your_password E:/in/File%G.csv"
```

Note the use of cygpath to convert from windows path style to something that cygwin understands. The SSH executable is a cygwin process so you need to convert to something it will be able to use.

Also, note the change from backslashes to forward slashes, again for some quirks in path separators between windows and cygwin.

If you have trouble with this (I can't test your code for you directly), then do this on a cygwin shell:

```
cygpath E:/path/to/file
```

and then check it outputs something like /e/path/to/file (or /cygpath/e/path/to/file if you haven't remapped our root drives).

Comment: what do you mean with full paths to binaries, would the full paths bethe best way to keep the command i provided as simple as possible

Comment: like in my case the path to bash. i did `c:\cygwin\bin\ssh.exe` on windows cmd line and it showed me the help for ssh, so knew it would work

Comment: so in your example you do both__?  you use the path to bash and then  run it? do not understand the login part....kind of confused, shell noob here

Comment: how would the command look like with full path to binaries? and with the wrapper: would i have to put "sshpass -p "password" scp  E:\in\File%G.csv openstack@remotecomp:/testfiles/" in the script, right?

Comment: sorry, my example is showing how to go from windows realm to the cygwin realm, but you can probably do it directly with `...DO c:\cygwin\bin\sshpass -p ...` but the args get all complicated, so just make your shell script do all that instead and call it like in my example, passing in the params you need it to use.

Comment: ok so the easiest would be FOR /L %G in (1 1 100) C:\cygwin\bin\sshpass.exe -p "password" scp  E:\in\File%G.csv user@remotecomp, right?

Comment: i didn't try that as the -p might be applied to the FOR command, hence why i always split the 2 halves of windows/cygwin so it's clear which args are for which part, and why i suggested using a wrapper

Comment: so would it all look like this_?                             #!/bin/bash
# sshcomm.sh 
sshpass -p "password" scp  E:\in\File$@.csv user@remotecomp:/test/ "

FOR /L %G in (1 1 100) DO C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "/sshcomm.sh %G"                                                                how does it have to look like if i want to pass the password as parameter as well?

Comment: i'll add to my answer

Comment: i understand,,,which path is  /home/youruser/callssh.sh? can that be a random folder on windows too where i have put callssh.sh?

Comment: yes it can be anywhere as you're specifying it, but you'll need to use the cygpath version of its directory so bash can find it